# Set up folder share between Ubuntu 16.10 and lubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, lubuntu, samba

I want to set up a folder share on my 2 PCs, one using Ubuntu16.10 and the other using Lubuntu 16.04.
I installed samba on both with all the dependancies, although I think there mught be some issue with the installation in lubuntu (samba is present in the menu, and I could edit the smb.conf file to add the share, but the GUI for it (system-config-samba) won't start.. it flashes on the screen for a split second then closes.

ATM on lubuntu I can see the shared folder on my ubuntu pc, this could be enough, but I wish I were able to do the same inverting the roles.

I will add a third and fourth PCs to the network later on, both using Win 10... no password or user needed, ("guest ok = yes" and "read only = no").